# How to get webmin working in Server 2008(X64)

Tags: windows-server-2008, webmin

I have installed [webmin in server 2008(howto)](http://www.webmin.com/windows.html) plus its dependencies [activeperl(howto)](http://docs.activestate.com/activeperl/5.16/install.html) under VirtualBox,
but I can not get it to work. That is what I did so far:

As per the [activeperl(howto)](http://docs.activestate.com/activeperl/5.16/install.html) I briefly turned off the server, cause otherwise, it will not work, even after a reboot.

I went to Start → Administrative Tools → Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager
select FQDN then right-click my FQDN, and then pressed Stop.

when installing ActivePerl the first time, it did not find my folder cause it was in a `perl64` folder, during the second time installing, I installed it in `C:\Perl`the rest of the installation was next, install.

I then started my Web server, right-click my FQDN → start

I then processed to download and install [WebminInstall.exe](http://download.webmin.com/download/windows/WebminInstall.exe), but after installation, Webmin could not find `http://localhost:1000/`? I've Googled, and the only thing I encountered was, that it is not supported on Windows Server 2008 and that it is best to install it on a Linux distribution.

I am a big fan of Linux, but This is a school project, and it specifically said to install it on Windows Server 2008. Although I have time, I would like to finish it up early, since at the moment I only finished 2 out of 10 assignments, I would like to make it 3 out of 10 :)

**Question**: *How to install Webmin on my Windows server 2008(x64)?*

**Note**: *If needed, I would happily install an x32bit version of server 2008*

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong http://localhost:1000 its https://localhost:10000 or use the server name https://webserver.name.here:10000 and its secure so you need to use https as above

Comment: Do you have a reference or more information you can offer to confirm this is indeed the OP's problem?